# Как заполнить словарь в Swift

Tags: массивы, swift

у меня есть массив с именами и массив с первыми буквами их имен. Мне нужно создать словарь где ключом будет буква имени а значением массив имен. Например`var array = ["Vanya", "Sveta", "Kolya", "Vika"]
var firstChar = ["V" , "S", "K"]`
а словарь должен быть `["V" : ["Vanya", "Vika"], "S" : ["Sveta"], "K" : "Kolya"]`
вот что у меня сейчас есть

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var data = ["Alan Douglas", "Bob", "Bethany Webster", "Casey Fleser", "Daniel Huckaby", "Michael Morrison", "Bobbbbbbb"]
var contactSection = [String]()
var contactDictionary = [String : [String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for dat in data {
        contactSection.append(String(dat.first!))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, Вы хотите массив имен - эти имена гарантированно первое слово строк в массвиве `data`? Если да, то получаете массив имен:

```
let names = data.compactMap{ $0.split(separator: " ").first }.map{ String($0) }
```

Затем из этого массива инициализируем Dictionary:

```
let namesDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: names, by: { String($0.first!) })
```

Резульат:

```
names содержит ["Alan", "Bob", "Bethany", "Casey", "Daniel", "Michael", "Bobbbbbbb"]
namesDictionary содержит ["B": ["Bob", "Bethany", "Bobbbbbbb"], "A": ["Alan"], "M": ["Michael"], "C": ["Casey"], "D": ["Daniel"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

можно так

```
let data = ["Alan Douglas", "Bob", "Bethany Webster", "Casey Fleser", "Daniel Huckaby", "Michael Morrison", "Bobbbbbbb"]
let dataDict = data.reduce(into: [String:[String]]()) { result, name in
    if result["\(name.first!)"] == nil {
        result["\(name.first!)"] = [name]
    } else {
        result["\(name.first!)"]!.append(name)
    }
}
// dataDict = ["C": ["Casey Fleser"], "M": ["Michael Morrison"], "B": ["Bob", "Bethany Webster", "Bobbbbbbb"], "A": ["Alan Douglas"], "D": ["Daniel Huckaby"]]
```